# Forces textbook question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, textbook-erratum

I have this textbook question:

[image]

This is the solution:

[image]

[image]

Can you please explain why the forces of the ground and gravity were added together, and why that resulted in the net force? I thought the net force would be the sum of the athlete's force and the ground's force plus the gravitational force?

Also, in the calculation of $\sum F_x$, there is an error in the second last line, right?

**I would like a general explanation of the rationale behind this solution.**

Comment: What is athlete's force? Athlete won't exert force in himself. The forces were added because to find net force, the forces will obviously be added, as long as the directions are taken into account! Yes there is an error there.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which textbook?

Answer (score 0):

The net force in the ground is also similar to when the athlete begins/does his jump. The ground will supply a force to counter his/her weight (F=mg) and an additional amount of force as the athlete accelerates upward (F=ma).